# Equivariant K-theory for products of groups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, equivariant-cohomology

Let $X$ be a $(G \times H)$-space. What is known about the connection between the groups $K_G(X)$, $K_H(X)$ and $K_{G \times H}(X)$? The $G$ and $H$ action on $X$ come from the canonical inclusions $G \to G \times H$ and $H \to G \times H$.

There is the Künneth theorem relating $K_G(X)$, $K_H(Y)$ and $K_{G \times H}(X \times Y)$, where $X$ is a $G$-space and $Y$ is a $H$-space. This only reduces to the above case when either $G$ or $H$ acts trivially (and the corresponding $X$ or $Y$ is a point).

I can't find anything in the literature, for K-theory or equivariant cohomology. Is there a specific reason why it is so hard to get information about $K_{G \times H}(X)$ from $K_G(X)$ and $K_H(X)$?

Comment: Let me mention that a $G\times H$-action carries potentially more structures than a $G$-action and an $H$-action. At least, there is a commutativity between two actions (and in higher algebra, such as the K-theory spectrum that you want to study, commutativity is an extra structure).

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the content of a paper of Minami (At least for compact Lie groups)

[*A Künneth formula for equivariant $K$-theory*. Haruo Minami. Osaka J. Math. 6(1): 143-146 (1969).](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-6/issue-1/A-K%C3%BCnneth-formula-for-equivariant-K-theory/ojm/1200692333.full)

Following ideas of Atiyah's proof of the Kunneth theorem for K-theory (non-equivariant) he obtain exactly the result you want.

As a final comment note that if $G$ acts on spaces $X$ and $Y$ it is too much hard to obtain $K_G(X\times Y)$ in terms of $K_G(X)$ and $K_G(Y)$

Comment: OP is asking for the case when both $G$ and $H$ are acting on the same space $X$, and interested in the $G\times H$ equivariant $K$-theory of $X$ (and not that of $X \times X$).